# Wordpress 4.2.2 update - failing wpdb->insert

Tags: mysql, wordpress

## context

I have been working on a new wordpress blog as a personal website. Part of it, I have a custom contact form where people put in their details to get in touch with me.It has been working good till morning, after which I have updated to 4.2.2v citing security reasons.

## problem

After the update, the form is failing to save any of the information into the DB. The `$wpdb->insert_id` is returning 0. The query is the same, the page is the same, everything is just the same. The only change is I have upgraded to 4.2.2v from 4.2.1v.

Is there any issue with the recent update or do I have to do any more steps after the [word press manual update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress) ?

## debugging done...

I have ensured that the DB version is updated. It is showing 31535. When debugging using the `$wpdb->lastquery` and `$wpdb->print_error()` I get

```
WordPress database error: []
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_tst_tbl_contacts`
```

## ?

I could not understand what is wrong here. If I run the same insert query, as well as the above `show full columns` on command line using the same user wp user credentials, it works perfectly.

note: If there is anymore information needed, please ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the problem cause. Its due to a column width limitation.

I have a VARCHAR(9) column and I was sending data that is 16 char length. The new change in the 4.2.2 gets the table meta and crops the data such that it fits properly into the size of the column as defined in DB. And it also compares the pre-crop and post-crop data. If they don't match, it is failing.

The problem is, its failing silently with no error thrown. I have found this via debugging the wpincludes/wp-db.php file.

Please check your column limit and the column data length you send.

Once I have increased the column width (as the data will definitely be more than 9 chars), the issue got resolved.

Comment: Thanks a lot! They should have put that in the changelog. It broke some functions of our website and we couldn't figure out why because we didn't change anything.

You deserve more upvotes :)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.2.2

Comment: There's no reason wordpress needs to check string lengths when MySQL is perfectly capable of truncating inserts for you. To fail silently is a horrible failure on Word Presses fault. Thanks for finding out why!

Comment: This error will also happen if your custom post_type is larger than 20 characters (default size of post_type column).

Comment: Confirmed, 4.6 does this too, often plugin authors forget that IP can have up to 50chars, so if they store entry to table where IP is e.g. VARCHAR 15 or even 20 and IPv6 user comes in - wpdb insert fails :)

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke If you've designed your app right, you should not need DB to truncate something for you... I think that is WP saying 'Hey dude, you have probably bad design!' - in many cases - that's the case :)

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this same issue and it turned out to be some unescaped values being pushed into the database from a csv import function.

I applied the proper `esc_url()` and / or `esc_attr()` and / or `esc_html()` where appropriate to sanitize the values pre-insertion and then the query ran successfully.